# how to run android simulator on a pc which doesnot support vt-x

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

my CPU doesn't support vt-x.
I want to develop apps in android studio.
tried genymotion but apparently it also requires vt-x
is there any alternate emulator that i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can download and use `ARM` images that do not need `hardware virtualization` instead of using `x86 system images`. Need to tell you that `ARM images` will be very slow compared to `x86 images`.

You can download `ARM image` of respective `APIs` by selecting this option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Visual Studio's Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx). You have to install Visual Studio 2015 RC to get it, but then you can run it without needing Visual Studio open. It uses Hyper-V, so it doesn't require vt-x, but it does require Windows 8 or later.